# Bringing little girls into the men's section in Shul

Tags: tefilla, women, synagogue, tznius-modesty, children-parenting

It has become the norm in mosts shuls I've been to, that fathers bring little girls into the men's section of synagogues on Shabbos and Yom Tov.

Until what age should girls still be allowed to brought in? And when should (or must) it be stopped?

Comment: As always, answers here are good for discussion; for practical halachic guidance, one should always rely on his local, orthodox rabbi.

Comment: Is this the same age for little boys going into the womem's section with their mothers?

Answer (score 6):

Rav Herschel Shachter is quoted as saying that he determined many of these issues with the following test.  He invited his (male) students over.  When they stopped treating his daughters as little children and didn't pick up the daughters, the daughters were old enough to dress modestly, etc.  I do not know how old this was, and given how old his daughters now are, I think the students are more inclined to pick them up metaphorically than literally.

Answer (score 3):

I found in [ילקוט יוסף](http://yalkut.info/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2-/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9A-%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8.htm) that from 8-9 years it could be a problem if girls wear not modest clothes.

> ז בנות קטנות בגיל שמונה או תשע שנים, הבאות לבית הכנסת עם אביהן בלבוש בלתי צנוע, בשמלות קצרות ביותר ובלי שרוולים, מן הדין יש מקום להקל לקרוא קריאת שמע ולברך כנגדן, שכיון שקטנות הן ורגילות בכך, לא שייך בהן הרהור כל כך. ואין בהן דין טפח באשה ערוה. ומכל מקום נכון להחמיר לעצום עיניו או להפוך פניו לצד אחר. ואכן הדבר ברור מאד שאסור להורים להלביש את בנותיהן בבגדי פריצות כאלה, שהרי צריך לחנכן שיתנהגו בצניעות, ומכל שכן שאין נכון כלל להביאן כך לבית הכנסת שעלול הדבר לבוא לידי מכשול, ואם כבר באו לבית הכנסת בלבוש כזה, טוב לשלוח אותן לעזרת נשים. [ילקוט יוסף, תשס''ד, ספר פסד''ז, עמוד תרסד. שאר''י ח''ב עמוד ריז]. ‏

However, when I CYLORed about from what age should I avoid reading Holy-Things (דבר שבקדושה) before my small daughter I was told that from 3 years it is preferred to close eyes.

Answer (score 2):

In my Shul they allow up to the age of 6. I have been told, yet do not have link, that HaRav Wosner Shlita in his Teshuvos writes up to a maximum of age 7.